# Umbraco url by content id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have a normal Umbraco project with standard urls i.e:

mydomain.com/contact/
mydomain.com/about/

But content in Umbraco also have ID's, so if I navigate to:

mydomain.com/1316.aspx

The above will still give me a live page with content, how do I disable this so there are no aspx pages except the standard ones I create?

I'm sorry this question is vague, I'm not so sure where to look or what information I'm really looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, a link to the relevant documentation would be sweet too as I can't seem to find any of relevance.

Comment: What Umbraco version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

So, I managed to fix this fairly easily actually by delving into the umbracoSettings.config

Inside of here you'll find a setting like the following:

```
<web.routing
     trySkipIisCustomErrors="false" internalRedirectPreservesTemplate="false" disableAlternativeTemplates="false" disableFindContentByIdPath="false"
     umbracoApplicationUrl="">
</web.routing>
```

Simply set *disableFindContentByIdPath* to true.